# How to offset image contents by X,Y pixels using ImageMagick?

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to offset the pixels in a PNG image by -1 in X and -4 in Y axis.

The images were converted from a PDF created by Corel Draw, which adds an offset, breaking the image processing system I'm working on.
align_image_stack from hugin-tools package crashes when processing these files, that's why I resort to trying a fixed offest correction.

I tried this these commands:

```
$ convert a.png: -geometry 100%-100-100 b.png

$ convert -region '100%+500px+100px' a.png b.png

$ convert -page '100%+500px+100px' a.png b.png

$ convert -repage '100%+500px+100px' a.png b.png

$ convert -crop '100%+500px+100px' a.png b.png

$ convert a.png -geometry 100%-100px-100px b.png
```

They have all finished without an error, but the gave me the same image I fed them as input.

**a.png = b.png**

What am I doing wrong? Why the Covert command does not shift the image contents?

EDIT:

Here's a pair of images to illustrate my problem. The first image is what  I want, the second is what comes out of Corel Draw, I want to apply an arbitrary X/Y offset to compensate for this difference. The images are faked only to illustrate the problem, this is not authentic data.

[image: Two images]

New point is that I was able to produce the offset **once**, but I can't reproduce this. It looks to me like a bug in ImageMagick, because I'm trying the same command that I used before and it doesn't work now.

I also tried using GraphicsMagick to doublechek this.

I was able to get an offset written to PNG header, but that doesn't make Blender use that offset, so I need to "burn" that offset into the bitmap data, not just specify it in the metadata.

This command did a change, but only GIMP seems understands that and I need to make Blender apply the offset:

```
convert a.png -repage '100%x100%+100+1000' b.png
```

I tried using -sample to apply the transformation, but it's not alpplied and stays in the metadata - I can check this with GIMP.

```
convert a.png -repage '100%x100%+100+1000' -sample 100% b.png
```

I can't believe I am unable to do such a simple thing.

Comment: How about sharing an image with an offset?

Comment: I can't publish the exact images as they belong to a client.

But I can illustrate the problem with different files.

Comment: Can't diagnose the problem from your illustration which is just a screen shot of the two images.  Get `pngcheck` and look at the result of `pngcheck -v a.png` and `pngcheck -v b.png`.  If the PNG contains an offset, it would be in the `oFFs` chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It is hard to understand what you want without proper images, but here is another attempt at guessing a solution for you. Let's start with this image - ignore the colours as I only added them so you can see the extent of the images and you can remove/change them anyway:

[image]

The new plan is to trim your image so there is no border around the letters at all and then to add in whatever border you want afterwards. So, trimming the existing border and adding a 10px border left and right and a 50px border top and bottom:

```
convert start.png -trim -bordercolor red -border 10x50 result.png
```

[image]

Or, trimming the original border and adding a 10px border to the right side  only:

```
convert start.png -trim -gravity east -background blue -splice 10x0 result.png
```

[image]

Hopefully that will give you an approach to achieve what you seek.

**Original Answer**

If you want to reset the page offsets back to zero, the easiest way is:

```
mogrify +repage image.png
```

Or, slightly harder:

```
convert image.png +repage result.png
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, becasue there is no offset specified in the file metadata that can be reset. I need to apply a custom offset.

Unfortunately none of the geometry related commands I used did any change to the image, they seem to be silently ignored,

I was ale to blur the image, change the gamma, flip it upside down, but not offset the pixels in the image.

Comment: @unfa I have had another attempt - please look again.

Comment: Looking at your updated answer - this is an interesting solution - and it actually could be a solution for me!

If I measure the margins on my "perfect" page, I can trim the image and add the border, making the image cropped properly.

Maybe if "splice" command can accept negative values, the whole thing could be easier, and work without the "trim" phase.

Comment: `mogrify +repage image.png` this was just what I needed! Thank you Mark!
I was trying to convert some tiff files which were originally exported from PDF files sent to professional printers, which had "Page geometry: 984x1432+47+23
  Origin geometry: +47+23" properties, causing pages to be shifted in image output.